# How to make this iterator/for loop idiomatic in Rust

Tags: rust

How can I get rid of the ugly `let mut i = 0;` and `i += 1;`? Is there a more idomatic way I can write this loop? I tried `.enumerate()` but it doesn't work on a &[&str].

```
use std::fmt::Write;

pub fn build_proverb(list: &[&str]) -> String {
    let mut proverb = String::new();
    let mut i = 0;
    for word in list {
        i += 1;
        if i < list.len() {
            write!(proverb, "For want of a {} the {} was lost.\n", word, list[i]);
        } else {
            write!(proverb, "And all for the want of a {}.", list[0]);
        }
    }
    proverb
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want this code to do? You pass in a list of words, what does the list look like? What do you expect it to output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, `enumerate()` doesn't exist for `&[&str]` because `enumerate()` is a function on `Iterator`, and `&[&str]` is not an `Iterator`.

But you can call `list.iter()` to get an iterator, which you can then call `enumerate()` on.

Full example:

```rust
pub fn build_proverb(list: &[&str]) -> String {
    let mut proverb = String::new();
    for (i, word) in list.iter().enumerate() {
        if i < list.len() {
            write!(proverb, "For want of a {} the {} was lost.\n", word, list[i]);
        } else {
            write!(proverb, "And all for the want of a {}.", list[0]);
        }
    }
    proverb
}
```

The fact you have `word` and `list[i]` (after incrementing `i`) makes it look like you want something like `windows`:

```rust
pub fn build_proverb(list: &[&str]) -> String {
    let mut proverb = String::new();

    for words in list.windows(2) {
        let first = words[0];
        let second = words[1];
        write!(proverb, "For want of a {} the {} was lost.\n", first, second);
    }
    write!(proverb, "And all for the want of a {}.", list[0]);
    proverb
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. Didn't know about `.windows(2)`, super useful.

Comment: There's also the currently-nightly-only `array_windows` which uses const generics to let you write: `for [first, second] in list.array_windows() { }` which gives a little bit of extra type safety. The array destructuring pattern `[first, second]` is used to infer the type, so you don't even have to type the number `2`